# Collect not working as intended in my loop for common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying to code a player in LISP to solve the game mastermind. In this environment: http://pastebin.com/8XW8HZza

I'm trying to have the player go through each color and guess mono-chromatically before sorting it into the right position. This is what I have so far:

```
(defvar *counter* 0)
(defvar *ElementsViewed* -1)
(defvar *CorrectColors* NIL)

(defun ith-element (list)
   (nth *ElementsViewed* list))

;analyze the score to determine whether points need to be added to counter
(defun analyze (last-response colors)

  (cond ((equal last-response nil)
     (setf *counter* 0)))

  (cond ((equal last-response nil)
      (setf *ElementsViewed* -1)))

  (cond ((equal last-response nil)
     (setf *CorrectColors* NIL)))

  (cond ((equal last-response nil) NIL)
     ((= (first last-response) 0))
     (T (setf *counter* (+ (first last-response) *counter*))))

  (cond ((equal last-response nil))
    ((= (first last-response) 0))
    (T (loop for i from 1 to (first last-response) do (setf *CorrectColors* (cons (ith-element colors) *CorrectColors*)))))
  )


;helper function for finding correct color
(defun guess-color (length colors)

  (print (ith-element colors))

  (loop for i from 1 to length collect (ith-element colors))

    )

(defun sort-color (length)
  (loop for i from 1 to length  
     for item in *CorrectColors*
     collect item))    

;baseline Holyguacamole player will guess all colors before trying all combinations of correct color 
(defun HolyGuacamole (board colors SCSA last-response)

  (declare (ignore SCSA))

  (print last-response)

  (analyze last-response colors)

  (print *counter*)

  (if (= *counter* board)
      (sort-color board))

  (setf *ElementsViewed* (1+ *ElementsViewed*))

  (guess-color board colors)

)
```

The player starts by guessing the right colors in the code. Each time a guess is made, the system returns a response (#correct #other #guess-so-far) where #correct is the number of correct colors in the correct peg position while #other is in the correct color in the wrong peg position. While the player adds the correct color each time it gets #correct into the list `*CorrectColors*`, it also adds a counter to determine whether it has collected all correct colors. Should it finish getting all the right colors, it goes to the function `sort-color`when I tried playing a game however, it doesn't seem to be running that function correctly as I have the following sample outputs:

> HOLYGUACAMOLE
>
> NIL
>
> 0
>
> A
>
> (0 0 1)
>
> 0
>
> B
>
> (0 0 2)
>
> 0
>
> C
>
> (0 0 3)
>
> 0
>
> D
>
> (2 0 4)
>
> 2
>
> E
>
> (0 0 5)
>
> 2
>
> F
>
> (0 0 6)
>
> 2
>
> G
>
> (0 0 7)
>
> 2
>
> H
>
> (1 0 8)
>
> 3
>
> I
>
> (0 0 9)
>
> 3
>
> J
>
> (1 0 10)
>
> 4
>
> NIL
>
> (SCORE -2)
>
> (0 0 1)

In the case of this game, I'm playing 4 pegs and 10 possibly colors. Once the counter hits 4, it should have collected the answer from `*CorrectColors*`. However, it never responds for that. What exactly am I doing wrong? I tried using

```
(defun sort-color (length)
  (loop for i from 1 to length  
     for item in *CorrectColors*
     do (print item)))
```

to test whether it's looping correctly and it does print out all the right colors. However, it doesn't seem to be returning the answer to the system.

Comment: You're calling `SORT-COLOR` without doing anything with the result, and the (non-printing version of the) function doesn't do any side effects. What are you expecting to happen when you call it?

Comment: @jkiiski I don't understand why it isn't doing anything though. For 'guess-color' I have more or less the same loop that uses 'collect' and it actually returns to me a response. Why wouldn't 'sort-color' do the same?

Comment: The return value of `GUESS-COLOR` is returned from `HOLYGUACAMOLE`, because it's the last form in it. `SORT-COLOR` is called before it, but since it's not the last form and you're not doing anything with its return value, it's discarded.

Comment: @jkiiski Ok, now I understand. I'm not too familiar with lisp, so I didn't know that. Thank you. What would you suggest? Would a `cond` statement work in this case? I would do that, but I need it so that the second condition runs both `(setf *ElementsViewed* (1+ *ElementsViewed*))` and  `guess-color` and I don't know exactly how.

Comment: A `COND` can have multiple forms in every clause. The value from the last form of the chosen clause will be returned.

Comment: @jkiiski so I can have the `setf` increment and `guess-color` run within the same clause?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129776/discussion-between-trungnt-and-jkiiski).